# How do i set filtering conditions per group?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For example, with the example dataset below, how do I set a filtering condition using jupyter notebook where I can find out who has 2 or more results of "Number of Candies" more than or equal to 3.1?

| ID | Name | Number of Candies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jerry | 3.1 |
| 1 | Jerry | 3 |
| 1 | Jerry | 2 |
| 2 | Tom | 6 |
| 2 | Tom | 5.8 |
| 3 | Wendy | 3.1 |
| 3 | Wendy | 3.2 |

Thus, the output after filtering should be

| ID | Name | Number of Candies |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Tom | 6 |
| 2 | Tom | 5.8 |
| 3 | Wendy | 3.1 |
| 3 | Wendy | 3.2 |

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this tagged `jupyter-notebook` and not `pandas`? It seems like a pandas-like question

Comment: Or the better question is, what do you use to read your data? Your own `class` or indeed `pandas`? What did you try and what did not work? i.e. show us some code so we can help you from there.

Comment: My bad, I'm using Pandas. I tried using pd. filter, but, I can only use one condition with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), we could do this in two steps:

0. Of course, first make sure you're using a numeric dtype in your "Number of Candies" column:

   ```
   df["Number of Candies"] = df["Number of Candies"].astype(float)
   ```
1. Filter rows where "Number of Candies" is more than or equal to 3.1

   ```
   df.loc[df["Number of Candies"] >= 3.1]
   ```
2. Then group  by "Name" and keep groups larger than or equal to 2

   ```
   .groupby("Name").filter(lambda group: len(group) >= 2)
   ```

You can put both conditions together and get the result you want in a single line:

```
>>> df.loc[df["Number of Candies"] >= 3.1].groupby("Name").filter(lambda group: len(group) >= 2)
   ID    Name  Number of Candies
3   2    Tom                 6.0
4   2    Tom                 5.8
5   3  Wendy                 3.1
6   3  Wendy                 3.2
```

Comment: Hello, tried this but got no output instead! Sorry forgot to mention that i am currently using pandas jupyter too.

Comment: What do you mean no output? Did you use the last line of code inside of a `print`?

Comment: Yup used print but only got the columns heading with "Empty Dataframe".

Comment: Are you sure your data has a numeric dtype? What's the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: Yup the dtype is float64

Comment: Does my answer work for you using the sample data you provided? Is it possible that no rows match your conditions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean mask computed per group:

```
#             is more than 3.1?       /    get count of True per group    / ≥ 2? 
mask = df['Number of Candies'].ge(3.1).groupby(df['ID']).transform('sum').ge(2)
df[mask]
```

output:

```
   ID   Name  Number of Candies
3   2    Tom                6.0
4   2    Tom                5.8
5   3  Wendy                3.1
6   3  Wendy                3.2
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this earlier  as well but i got this instead

output:

0   False
1   False
2   False
3   False

Comment: @DT can you update the question and provide the DataFrame constructor?

Comment: I'm using Pandas jupyter. So sorry forgot to include it in the post.

Comment: @DT you should provide it as a html table is always ambiguous in terms of data type

Comment: Yup my bad forgot to include it in

Comment: @DT and… will you now include it? ;)